# How to find BitStamp's Ripple address?

Tags: ripple, ripple-gateways, bitstamp

I see [on the wiki](https://ripple.com/wiki/Gateway_List) that they're the 2nd Gateway, but don't see anything about it on their site.

Comment: People shouldn't trust any Ripple addresses not listed/provided by the gateway themselves so I'm not sure if this type of question is appropriate for SE. (Unless it was changed to be general about getting the address of any gateway).

Comment: @dchapes - well, the link in the answer seems to require a login. I think it's important to publicly expose the information. Perhaps the answer should just be qualified with a disclaimer?

Comment: I still think this question should at least be changed to ask how to find any gateway's address. But I could be wrong :) I'm not sure, but I wonder if https://ripple.com/wiki/Gateway_List doesn't including Ripple addresses for a reason.

Comment: @dchapes - I forgot to mention that I did edit the question... but I don't want to make it too general, it has a specific answer anyway, changing it to a general question won't make sense at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under [Withdrawal/Ripple](https://www.bitstamp.net/account/withdraw/ripple/) there is a link named "trust this address".

(removed from here the address itself due to a good suggestion: don't trust what is written here, go there and have a look yourself)

Comment: Can you add a disclaimer as per http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7877/how-to-find-bitstamps-ripple-address?noredirect=1#comment14213_7877 ?